# "npm outdated" shows nothing listed for latest

Tags: npm, npm-outdated

When I run "npm outdated", it doesn't show anything for "Latest". All of the @angular packages should have a latest version of at least 4.4.6, and I expect most of the other ones should have newer versions as well. What is listed under "Current" is what is in my package.json file.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with latest windows 10 version using powershell.

A quick workaround is to just use the regular CMD window.

Windows Key + R ---> cmd